# Python TWS Interactive Broker Attribute error

Tags: python, api, interactive-brokers, tws

> when i run this code i get attribute error but can't get result from API
> POSITIONS IN MY ACCOUNT ARE NOT PRINTED OUT.
> ALSO THE CODE (print("Position", contract.symbol, position, avgCost) IN THE DEF POSITION) IS NOT EXECUTED
> I am getting attribute error that

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
158             contract.currency="USD"
159
--> 160             my.ib.reqMktData(1, contract, "", True, False, [])
161
162             print(symbols)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ib'

````
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.contract import Contract
from ibapi.order import *
from ibapi.ticktype import TickTypeEnum
from ibapi.scanner import ScannerSubscription
from ibapi.scanner import ScanData
from ibapi.execution import ExecutionFilter
from threading import Timer
from threading import Thread
import threading
import time
import math

symbols = ["MSFT", "C", "SNBR", "LMND"]
quantitys=[1, 2, 3, 4]
pricemoves=[0.5, 1, 1.5, 0.9]
buyorderids=[1,2,3,4]
sellorderids=[1,2,3,4]
currentprices=[0]*4
executions=[]
executionfilter=ExecutionFilter()

numsymbol=len(symbols)
class TestApp(EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)
        self.position_symbols=[]
        self.position_shares=[]

    def error(self, reqId, errorCode, errorString):
        print('Error: ', reqId, " ", errorCode, " ", errorString)
        
    def position(self, account, contract, position, avgCost):
        super().position(account, contract, position, avgCost)
        print("Position", contract.symbol, position, avgCost)
        self.position_symbols.append(contract.symbol)
        self.position_shares.append(str(position)) 
      
    def historicalData(self, reqId, bar):
        print('HistoricalData. ', reqId, 'Date: ', bar.date, 'Open:', bar.open, 'High:', bar.high, 'Low:', bar.low,
              'Close:', bar.close, 'Volume:', bar.volume, 'Count:', bar.barCount)
        
    def tickPrice(self, reqId, tickType, price, attrib):
        currentprices.append(price)

    def execDetails(self, reqId, contract, execution):
        executions.append(execution)

    def nextValidId(self, orderId):
        self.nextOrderId = orderId
        self.start()

    def start(self):
        self.reqPositions()
         
    def stop(self):
        self.done = True
        self.cancelScannerSubscription(1)
        self.disconnect()

class MyThread(Thread, EWrapper, EClient): 
    ib=None
    def __init__(self):
        self.ib=TestApp()
        Thread.__init__(self)

        self.start()

        self.ib.connect('127.0.0.1', 7497, 0)
        app = TestApp()
        app.nextOrderId = 0
        
    def run(self):
        for i in range (332, 345, 2):
            time.sleep(4)
            # print(i)
            loopindex = i % numsymbol

# THE TWO LINES OF CODES BELOW DO NOT WORK. THERE ARE NO ERROR MESSAGES CREATED, BUT THE POSITIONS IN MY ACCOUNT ARE NOT PRINTED OUT. 
# ALSO THE CODE (print("Position", contract.symbol, position, avgCost) IN THE DEF POSITION) IS NOT EXECUTED

        print(self.ib.position_symbols)
        print(self.ib.position_shares)

        thissymbol=symbols[loopindex]
        thispricemove=pricemoves[loopindex]
        thisquantity=quantitys[loopindex]

        # MARKET PRICE
        contract=Contract()
        contract.symbol=thissymbol
        contract.secType="STK"
        contract.exchange="SMART"
        contract.currency="USD"
        self.ib.reqRealTimeBars(0, contract, 5, "TRADES", 1, [])
        
        # BUY ORDER
        order=Order()
        order.action="BUY"
        order.orderType="MKT"
        order.totalQuantity=thisquantity

        contract=Contract()
        contract.symbol=thissymbol
        contract.secType="STK"
        contract.exchange="SMART"
        contract.primaryExchange="ISLAND"
        contract.currency="USD"
         
        self.ib.placeOrder(i,contract,order)

        # SELL ORDER
        order=Order()
        order.action="SELL"
        order.orderType="MKT"
        order.totalQuantity=thisquantity

        contract=Contract()
        contract.symbol=thissymbol
        contract.secType="STK"
        contract.exchange="SMART"
        contract.primaryExchange="ISLAND"
        contract.currency="USD"
        self.ib.placeOrder(i+1,contract,order)

        # HANDLE ORDER ID
        buyorderids[loopindex]=i
        sellorderids[loopindex]=i+1
        print(i)

        self.ib.reqMktData(1, contract, "", True, False, []) 
        print(currentprices)

        self.ib.reqExecutions(10001, executionfilter)
        print(executions)
        

my = None
while True:
    user_input = input("What do I do?")
    if user_input == "start thread":
        if my == None: 
            my = MyThread()

    elif user_input.upper() in ["REMOVE", "ADD"]:
        
        symbol = input("Enter stock symbol:")
        if user_input.upper() == "ADD": 
            symbols.append(symbol.upper())

            contract=Contract()
            contract.symbol=user_input.upper()
            contract.secType="STK"
            contract.exchange="SMART"
            contract.primaryExchange="ISLAND"
            contract.currency="USD"

            my.ib.reqMktData(1, contract, "", True, False, []) 

            print(symbols)
        elif user_input.upper() == "REMOVE":
            index=symbols.index(symbol.upper())
            del symbols[index]
            del quantitys[index]
            del pricemoves[index]
            del sellorderids[index]
            del buyorderids[index]  
            print(symbols)```
````

Comment: any body please answer that i need it asap?

Comment: Did you make sure you ran start-thread command first and verified that you got a valid connection? Otherwise, the object my is never initialized.